# how to run application of spring batch using CommandLineJobRunner

Tags: spring-batch

I am creating an application using spring batch in which i am reading data from database and populate it in a file placed in D drive. My application does not have any errors but when i run my app, the console does not show any exceptions. In fact, the console is blank completely. I am not able to figure out if the app is actually getting executed or not. 
I am using CommandLineJobRunner class for executing my job.

All your comments would be of great help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- *Reading data from database and populate it in a file placed in D drive*
- *I am not able to figure out if the app is actually getting executed or not*

Did you check the `D` drive? Is the file there? Was it populated as expected?

As a rule of thumb => write a test, that would make sure the file is there on the `D` drive, and that it has all the data expected. But as a start, you can just check it manually.

As to your question => The reason that you do not see anything, is most likely related to the **logging misconfiguration**.

If you use `log4j` / `slf4j` / etc, make sure to place a default (for a start) `lo4j.properties` / `lo4j.xml` file in your class path [e.g. root of your project]. If you use `logback`, make sure a `logback.xml` is in your classpath with (for a start) default configuration:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.root.level.package" level="debug"/>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you develop your application using an IDE like Eclipse? If so, you might try debugging your code so that you can find out the reason why your application is not working as you expected it to be.